# Can an Entity Be Associated By More Than 1 Entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

So let's assume I have the following entities and their context configuration set up as follows. I have omitted a lot of properties for brevity's sake:

```
public class Company {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
}

public class Customer {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
}

public class Location {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public sealed class EntityDefaultContext : DbContext {
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().HasKey(m => m.Id).ToTable("Company");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().Property(m => m.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().HasRequired(m => m.Location).WithRequiredDependent().Map(m => m.MapKey("LocationId"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().HasKey(m => m.Id).ToTable("Customer");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().Property(m => m.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().HasRequired(m => m.Location).WithRequiredDependent().Map(m => m.MapKey("LocationId"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<Location>().HasKey(m => m.Id).ToTable("Location");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Location>().Property(m => m.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
    }
}
```

So as you can see, both the Company and Customer entities hold a reference to the Location entity. Something that would normally be expected I believe.

I set up my DB context for just that as you can also see. But the SQL that EF generates is terribly inefficient:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[LocationId] AS [LocationId], 
    [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id1]
FROM
    [dbo].[Customer] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Company] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[LocationId] = [Extent2].[LocationId]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Company] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[LocationId] = [Extent3].[LocationId]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Company] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent1].[LocationId] = [Extent4].[LocationId]
```

This is generated when I do something like this:

```
var q = from c in defaultContext.Set<Customer>().Include(m => m.Location)
        select c;
```

I am doing it like this for reasons that are not relevant to the question. The weird thing is that here is the SQL if I only configure the Location entity to be associated by only the Customer entity:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[LocationId] AS [LocationId]
FROM
    [dbo].[Customer] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Location] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[LocationId] = [Extent2].[Id]
```

Which is what I would expect. This makes me think. Does EF not support this scenario? How could it not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That can't be right.  Why would it join Company to the query when you are querying Customer?  There are no backwards navigation properties back to company.  In faction, Location isn't even part of the query, despite the fact you are including it.  So either you are presenting the wrong queries, or something really weird is going on.  Notice how the query lists Extent3 in the select field but Extent3 is not defined in the From?

Comment: Why do you map it as one-to-one? Try to map it as one-to-many where location can have multiple customers and companies.

Comment: @MystereMan You're right. That's my mistake. I posted an incorrect code snippet for that second example. I fixed it now.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka Genius! I misunderstood the API completely. I thought the "WithRequiredDependent" method just established a required property. I did not know it established a 1:1 relationship. I fixed it to use "WithMany" instead and it worked like a charm! If you post this as an answer, I would be happy to mark it as the correct one. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original mapping uses one-to-one relation. That always causes some special behavior. Moreover it has some other requirements to work correctly. What you probably want is one-to-many relation between `Customer` and `Location` and `Company` and `Location`. Change `WithRequiredDependent` to `WithMany` and it should work.

Comment: Thank you. Is "some special behavior" documented anywhere?  I looked at RequiredNavigationPropertyConfiguration.WithRequiredDependent on MSDN and didn't read anything about this behavior.